# How to compare temporary columns created from select in order to calculate SLA?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is the whole query that I have now, the first part seems to be fine but starting from "Y as" it shows all the columns underlined with red. I have marked the statements in bold which shows a red underline. I need to calculate the percentage of SLA which I was not able to figure out with this query. The business hours are SAturday-sunday from 4:30 am to 5:30pm and Mon-Friday from 4:30am to 10:30pm.

```
SELECT
    [JOB_TICKET].[JOB_TICKET_ID],
    [JOB_TICKET].[REPORT_DATE],
    [JOB_TICKET].[FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE],
    [JOB_TICKET].CLOSE_DATE,
    ,[JOB_TICKET].LAST_UPDATED,
    [PRIORITY_TYPE].[PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME] AS 'Ticket_Priority' ,
    DATEDIFF(MINute, report_date,FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE) as 'time_to_accept' ,
    sum (CASE 
         WHEN (DATEDIFF(MINute,report_date,FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE) <= '10' )
           THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
       END) AS "SLA time_to_accept Status",
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE,[JOB_TICKET].[FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE],[JOB_TICKET].[CLOSE_DATE]) as 'time_to_resolve' ,
    (CASE 
          when PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME='low' 
            then sum(case 
                       when DATEDIFF(MINUTE,[JOB_TICKET].[FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE],[JOB_TICKET].[CLOSE_DATE]) <= '960' 
                         then 1 
                         else 0 
                       end ) 
          when PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME='medium' 
            then sum(case 
                       when DATEDIFF(MINUTE[JOB_TICKET].[FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE],[JOB_TICKET].[CLOSE_DATE]) <= '480' 
                         then 1  
                         else 0 
                       end )  
          when PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME='high' 
            then sum(case
                        when DATEDIFF(MINUTE,[JOB_TICKET].[FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE],[JOB_TICKET]. [CLOSE_DATE]) <= '120' 
                          then 1  
                          else 0 
                        end )
          when PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME='Urgent' 
            then sum(case 
                        when DATEDIFF(MINUTE,[JOB_TICKET].[FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE],[JOB_TICKET].  [CLOSE_DATE]) <= '60' 
                          then 1 
                          else 0   
                        end)   
          end) as "Closed within SLA"  FROM [SWHD01].[dbo].[JOB_TICKET] INNER JOIN [SWHD01].[dbo].[STATUS_TYPE] ON [JOB_TICKET].[STATUS_TYPE_ID] =[STATUS_TYPE].[STATUS_TYPE_ID] INNER JOIN [SWHD01].[dbo].[PROBLEM_TYPE] ON [JOB_TICKET].[PROBLEM_TYPE_ID] = [PROBLEM_TYPE].[PROBLEM_TYPE_ID]  INNER JOIN [SWHD01].[dbo].[PRIORITY_TYPE] ON [JOB_TICKET].[PRIORITY_TYPE_ID] = [PRIORITY_TYPE].[PRIORITY_TYPE_ID] where REPORT_DATE is not null and DATEDIFF(MINUTE,[JOB_TICKET].[FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE],[JOB_TICKET].[CLOSE_DATE]) is not null and DATEDIFF(MINUTE,[JOB_TICKET].[FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE],[JOB_TICKET].[CLOSE_DATE]) > 0 group by JOB_TICKET_ID,[JOB_TICKET].[REPORT_DATE],[JOB_TICKET].[FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE],
  [JOB_TICKET].CLOSE_DATE,[JOB_TICKET].LAST_UPDATED,[PRIORITY_TYPE].[PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME]
```

Comment: some sample data
JOB_TICKET_ID Open_DATE FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE CLOSE_DATE LAST_UPDATED Ticket_Priority time_to_accept SLA time_to_accept Status time_to_resolve Closed within SLA
28257 1/1/15 0:00 1/1/15 0:01 1/1/15 1:25 1/1/15 1:25 Low 1 sla met 84 sla met
28262 1/1/15 0:18 1/1/15 0:21 1/1/15 0:24 1/1/15 0:24 Low 3 sla met 3 sla met

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Since you need to reuse `time_to_accept` and `time_to_resolve`, use a CTE so you don't have to repeat those long `DATEDIFF` expressions.
- Use another CTE so you don't have to repeat the long `CASE` expressions for
  `time_to_accept and`time_to_resolve.
- Finally, you completely left out
  the `FROM` statement from your primary `SELECT`; I've added `FROM SomeTable` as a placeholder.

.

```
WITH X AS (
SELECT
    [JOB_TICKET].[JOB_TICKET_ID],
    [JOB_TICKET].[REPORT_DATE],
    [JOB_TICKET].[FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE],
    [JOB_TICKET].CLOSE_DATE,
    [JOB_TICKET].LAST_UPDATED,
    [PRIORITY_TYPE].[PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME] AS 'Ticket_Priority',
    DATEDIFF(MINute, report_date,FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE) as 'time_to_accept',
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE,[JOB_TICKET].[FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE],[JOB_TICKET].[CLOSE_DATE]) as 'time_to_resolve'
FROM SomeTable
), 
Y AS (
SELECT
    X.JOB_TICKET_ID,
    X.REPORT_DATE,
    X.FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE,
    X.CLOSE_DATE,
    X.LAST_UPDATED,
    X.Ticket_Priority,
    X.time_to_accept,
    X.time_to_resolve,
    case when time_to_accept <= 10 then 1 else 0 end 
        AS "SLA time_to_accept Status",
    case when time_to_resolve <= case PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME
                                   WHEN 'low' then 960
                                   WHEN 'medium' then 480
                                   WHEN 'high' then 120
                                   WHEN 'Urgent' then 60
                                   END
      then 1
      else 0 end
        AS "Closed within SLA"
)

SELECT 
    Y.JOB_TICKET_ID,
    Y.REPORT_DATE,
    Y.FIRST_RESPONSE_DATE,
    Y.CLOSE_DATE,
    Y.LAST_UPDATED,
    Y.Ticket_Priority,
    Y.time_to_accept,
    Y.time_to_resolve,
    Y.[SLA time_to_accept Status],
    Y.[Closed within SLA],
    case WHEN [SLA time_to_accept Status]=1 and [Closed within SLA]=1
      then 1
      else 0
      end
        AS [SLA Compliant]
FROM Y
```

Comment: Hi ross presser,                                                                                     thank you so much for your valuable inputs, I forgot to the add the whole query at the first place. I have aded it now. I need to calculate the percentage of SLA which I was not able to figure out with this query. The business hours are SAturday-sunday from 4:30 am to 5:30pm and Mon-Friday from 4:30am to 10:30pm.

Comment: hi sir could you also add a condition to consider only business  hours to your query so that i only fetch tickets that fall within the business hours frame.The business hours are SAturday-sunday from 4:30 am to 5:30pm and Mon-Friday from 4:30am to 10:30pm and exclude holidays @RossPresser

Comment: I've given you more than enough to get started. Learn SQL and finish it.